# Why am I getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: st.replace is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, str-replace

I trying to build a portfolio. I am not a javascript expert and am not sure what to remove, or what is at fault. The page works fine but as soon as I try to go to the homepage the exit is very slow and the console throws an error.

*"Uncaught TypeError: st.replace is not a function"*

This snippet below is the piece that is faulty and gives me the error as soon as I click the home button to navigate away from the 'services' page.

Any instructions to as what is incorrect in the snippet are appreciated, thank you.

```
            htmlDoc: function(st) {
                var n, i = e(),
                    r = /<(\/?)(html|head|body|title|base|meta)(\s+[^>]*)?>/gi,
                    o = "ss" + Math.round(1e5 * Math.random()),
                    a = st.replace(r, function(t, n, r, a) {
                        var s = {};
                        return n || (e.merge(i, e("<" + r + "/>")), a && e.each(e("<div" + a + "/>")[0].attributes, function(e, t) {
                            s[t.name] = t.value
                        }), i.eq(-1).attr(s)), "<" + n + "div" + (n ? "" : ' id="' + o + (i.length - 1) + '"') + ">"
                    });
                return i.length ? (n || (n = e("<div/>")), n.html(a), e.each(i, function(e) {
                    var t = n.find("#" + o + e).before(i[e]);
                    i.eq(e).html(t.contents()), t.remove()
                }), n.children().unwrap()) : e(t)
            },
```

**EDIT FelixKling**

Thanks, @FelixKling Is seems to have several values:

"st = /-([\da-z])/gi,"

and

" st = ":(" + rt + ")(?:((('((?:\\.|[^\\'])*)'|\"((?:\\.|[^\\\"])*)\")|((?:\\.|[^\()[]]|" + at + ")*)|.*))|)", "

and

" St = ["Top", "Right", "Bottom", "Left"], "

but the last one has a Capital letter S. Please copy paste this answer to read it more cleartly. If i need to explain some more please let me know.

Comment: Well, what's the value of `st`? It doesn't seem to be a string. Make sure to pass a string. I.e. the problem is not with this code.

Comment: `console.log(typeof st);`. It's not a string and your problem is higher up.

Comment: How is this `htmlDoc` function called?

Comment: Thanks, @FelixKling. Is seems to have several values: 

"st = /-([\da-z])/gi,"

and 

"            st = ":(" + rt + ")(?:\\((('((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'])*)'|\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\")|((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\()[\\]]|" + at + ")*)|.*)\\)|)",
"

and 

"        St = ["Top", "Right", "Bottom", "Left"],
" but the last one has a Capital letter S. Please copy paste this answer to read it more cleartly. If i need to explain some more please let me know.

Comment: @krekettek _Please_ don’t put important details such as these into comments, especially if it’s long pieces of code. Instead, [edit] your question and include them there!

Comment: @Jaw.sh please see the comment i placed for Felix Kling. Do you think that is enough info to form a conclusion? I want to paste the entire .js but understand that is not allowed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that `st` is not a string.  Add a verification line to the top of the function that makes sure the argument is of the type expected.

```
if (typeof st !== 'string') {
    // HANDLE IT HERE (throw an error, return false/null, whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did as you said and now the log throws:


alles.js:4180 

Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

a.htmlDoc @ alles.js:4180 

a.getContentById @ alles.js:4205 

d @ alles.js:4263 

(anonymous function) @ alles.js:4277
i @ alles.js:2019rt.event.dispatch @ alles.js:1828
g.handle @ alles.js:1771
rt.event.trigger @ alles.js:1807
(anonymous function) @ alles.js:2040
rt.extend.each @ alles.js:575rt.fn.rt.each @ alles.js:478
rt.fn.extend.trigger @ alles.js:2039
(anonymous function) @ alles.js:4296